# Why can I access my eloquent relationship directly, but not eager load it using with()?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Running Laravel 6.20.7. My relationship is pretty straightforward. Define on my `OrderHoldHeader` class:

```
public function lines(){
    return $this->hasMany(OrderHoldLine::class, 'ORDER_ID');
}
```

I can access the relationship "lines" directly like so:

```
$pending_orders = OrderHoldHeader::first();
dd($pending_orders->lines);
```

This outputs the collection as expected:

[image]

I'd like to eager load the relationship, to neatly pass in these "lines" to my view, with each "header". I'm querying like so:

```
$pending_orders = OrderHoldHeader::with('lines')->first();
dd($pending_orders);
```

However, a quick DD shows an empty relationship collection.

[image]

It might be worth mentioning that I *have* tried defining the inverse of the relationship on the `OrderHoldLine` model with no luck.

Answer (score -1):

Try it:

```
$pending_orders = OrderHoldHeader::with('lines')->first()->toArray();
dd($pending_orders);
```

Also change it:

```
public function lines(){
    return $this->hasMany(OrderHoldLine::class, 'id', 'ORDER_ID');
}
```

Comment: This just returns an array rather than a collection, which still holds an empty relationship `lines`.